# Haskell - Append to a list inside a list of lists and return the lists of lists updated

Tags: list, haskell, append

Having spent hours looking for ways to manipulate `[[a]]` into `[[a]]`, I thought this would be the best solution to my problem. The problem consists of appending `a` to `[a]` and returning `[[a]]` with the new change.

For example: `xs = [[a],[b],[c]]` and `y = d`.

I want to append `y` to `xs!!0` . I cannot use `xs!!0 ++ y` because it will return just `[a,d]`, I know this is because of Haskell's immutability.

How would I go about appending a value to a sublist and returning the list of lists? - `[[a,d],[b],[c]]` using the example from above to illustrate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let { xs = [[1]] ; y = 2 ; zs = [(xs!!0) ++ [y]] } in zs` is one example to try at the GHCi prompt.

It returns `[[1,2]]`.

And for the case of e.g. `[[1],[2,3],[4]]` and the like, we can do

```
appendToFirst :: [[a]] -> a -> [[a]]
appendToFirst (xs:r) y  =  (xs ++ [y]) : r
```

so that

```
> appendToFirst [[1],[2,3],[4]] 0
[[1,0],[2,3],[4]]
```

The `(xs:r)` on the left of the equal sign is a *pattern*.

The `(:)` in the `( (...) : r)` on the right of the equal sign is a "`cons`" operation, a data constructor, `(:) :: t -> [t] -> [t]`.

`xs` is bound to the input list's "head" i.e. its first element, and `r` is bound to the rest of the input list, in the pattern; and thus `xs`'s value is used in creating the updated version of the list, with the first sublist changed by appending a value to its end, and `r` remaining as is.

`xs ++ [y]` creates a *new* entity, new list, while `xs` and `y` continue to refer to the same old values they were defined as. Since Haskell's values and variables are immutable, as you indeed have mentioned.

---

*edit:* If you want to add new element at the end of some sublist *in the middle*, not the first one as shown above, this can be done with e.g. `splitAt` function, like

```
appendInTheMiddle :: Int -> a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
appendInTheMiddle i y xs  =  
     let
        (a,b) = splitAt i xs
     in
        init a ++ [last a ++ [y]] ++ b
```

Trying it out:

```
> appendInTheMiddle 2 0 [[1],[2],[3],[4]]
[[1],[2,0],[3],[4]]
```

Adding the error-handling, bounds checking, and adjusting the indexing if 0-based one is desired (that one would lead to a simpler and faster code, by the way), is left as an exercise for the reader.

Syntactically, this can be streamlined with "view patterns", as

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

appendInTheMiddle :: Int -> a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
appendInTheMiddle i y (splitAt i -> (a,b))  =
        init a ++ [last a ++ [y]] ++ b
```

Comment: How could I adapt it such that I can append  y   (as you have called it) at any point in   xs    using a pointer? So append y to xs!!n and return xs.
I have tried changing it to (q:xs:r) and similar combinations but the results were not consistant as it was going for the propoertionate values. Thanks!

Comment: (OK, I've added this to the answer. :) )

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly and very good explanation :))